# ANT Landscape cannot be selected

Tags: mesh, add-on

I went to my preference, added the ANT Landscape Mesh. When I'm back in the add section I see landscape, but it is dimmed out compared to the others. I see it, but I cannot click on it to activate it.
I'm running window 10 PC.

Help anyone?

Comment: Idk know what you mean by faded. Have you tried adding another random object and see if it works then?

Comment: Share a screenshot.

Comment: Faded like not a bright highlighted name. Compared to the others Landscape is dimmed out almost. It's like it's there but I cannot click on it to activate it.